# netcdf on windows - fatal error: netcdf: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, netcdf

I'm working on a windows architecture, and I have this code in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
# set netcdf library element according to operating system
if(WIN32 OR MINGW)
    add_library(netcdf SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(netcdf PROPERTIES 
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "/mingw64/bin/libnetcdf.dll"
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB "/mingw64/bin/libnetcdf.dll.a"
    )
    set(NETCDF_LIB "netcdf")
else() # Linux or Mac
    set(NETCDF_LIB _trycompile_netcdf::NetCDF)
endif()

message(STATUS "[cedbManagement- CMakeLists.txt]: NETCDF_LIB ${NETCDF_LIB}")

# Build library and test and install library
buildAndInstallTarget("CedbManagement" "${sources}" "${test_sources}" "DMF03::"
                    LIB_DEPENDENCIES DMF03::Common ${NETCDF_LIB} DMF03::Geometry DMF03::FocusWrapper
                    WITH_TESTING ${BUILD_TESTING_DMF03}
                    TEST_WORKING_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../data")
```

Where buildAndInstallTarget have this code:

```
    # Helper function to build and install libraries and unit tests
    function(buildAndInstallTarget targetName libSources testSources nameSpace)
        # cmake_parse_arguments(prefix "nullary-args" "unary-args" "nary-args" args...)
        # The following arguments are optional:     
        #   WITH_TESTING: builds test target
        #   TEST_WORKING_DIR: test working directory
        #   EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIRS: additional include directories
        #   LIB_DEPENDENCIES: library dependecies
        #   TEST_DEPENDENCIES: test library dependecies
        #   TEST_EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIRS: additional include directories for tests
        cmake_parse_arguments(ARG "" "TEST_WORKING_DIR;WITH_TESTING" "LIB_DEPENDENCIES;TEST_DEPENDENCIES;EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIRS;TEST_EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIRS" ${ARGN})
        
        # Build the library
        set(libTarget ${targetName})
        add_library(${libTarget} STATIC ${libSources})
        
        # Add other dependencies
        foreach(lib IN LISTS ARG_LIB_DEPENDENCIES)
            target_link_libraries(${libTarget} ${lib})
        endforeach()
        
        # Include the headers   
        target_include_directories(${libTarget} PUBLIC
            $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
            $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        )
        foreach(extraInclude IN LISTS ARG_EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIRS)
            target_include_directories(${libTarget} PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${extraInclude}>)
        endforeach()
        
        # Install the library
        install_and_export_lib(${libTarget} EXPORT ${libTarget} NAMESPACE ${nameSpace})
        install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION include FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h*")
        foreach(extraInclude IN LISTS ARG_EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIRS)
            install(DIRECTORY ${extraInclude}/ DESTINATION include FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h*")
        endforeach()
            
        # If there are test sources, build a test executable
        if (testSources AND ARG_WITH_TESTING)
            set(testTarget "${targetName}Tests")
            add_executable(${testTarget} "${testSources}")
            foreach(extraInclude IN LISTS ARG_TEST_EXTRA_INCLUDE_DIRS)
                target_include_directories(${testTarget} PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${extraInclude}>)
            endforeach()
            set(allTestDependencies GTest::Main ${libTarget} "${ARG_TEST_DEPENDENCIES}")
            foreach(lib IN LISTS allTestDependencies)
                target_link_libraries(${testTarget} ${lib})
            endforeach()
            
            # Set working directory
            gtest_discover_tests(${testTarget} WORKING_DIRECTORY ${ARG_TEST_WORKING_DIR})
        endif ()
    endfunction(buildAndInstallTarget)
    
    # Set the version
    if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_UTILS_VERSION)
        set(CMAKE_UTILS_VERSION ${CURRENT_CMAKE_UTILS_VERSION})
    endif ()
endif ()
```

Cmake is working properly but, when during make run, I obtain this error:

> In file included from
> C:/builds/sdo/drama_oscar/dmf03_6dofsimulator/code/cedbManagement/src/NetCDFReader.cpp:13:
> C:/builds/sdo/drama_oscar/dmf03_6dofsimulator/code/cedbManagement/include/NetCDFReader.h:14:10:
> fatal error: netcdf: No such file or directory    14 | #include
>
> |          ^~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.

Anyone know what might be happening?

In case it helps, I searched the whole system for ntcdf, and this is the result:

> $ msys2 -c 'grep -ri netcdf / 2>/dev/null' Binary file
> /mingw64/bin/libnetcdf.dll matches /mingw64/bin/nc-config:# various
> things about the netCDF installation. This code was
> /mingw64/bin/nc-config:# contributed by netCDF user Arlindo DaSilva.
> Thanks Arlindo! /mingw64/bin/nc-config:libs="-L/mingw64/lib -lnetcdf"
> /mingw64/bin/nc-config:has_pnetcdf="" /mingw64/bin/nc-config:if [ -z
> "$has_pnetcdf" -o "$has_pnetcdf" = "OFF" ]; then
> /mingw64/bin/nc-config:    has_pnetcdf="no" /mingw64/bin/nc-config:
> has_pnetcdf="yes" /mingw64/bin/nc-config:version="netCDF 4.9.2"
> /mingw64/bin/nc-config:  --has-nc2          whether NetCDF-2 API is
> enabled /mingw64/bin/nc-config:  --has-nc4          whether
> NetCDF-4/HDF-5 is enabled in this build /mingw64/bin/nc-config:
> --has-pnetcdf      whether PnetCDF was used in build /mingw64/bin/nc-config:  --has-parallel     whether has parallel IO
> support via HDF5 or PnetCDF /mingw64/bin/nc-config:  --libs
> library linking information for netcdf /mingw64/bin/nc-config:
> --static        library linking information for statically-compiled netcdf /mingw64/bin/nc-config:        echo "  --has-pnetcdf      ->
> $has_pnetcdf" /mingw64/bin/nc-config:    --has-pnetcdf)
> /mingw64/bin/nc-config:        echo $has_pnetcdf
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#ifndef *NETCDF*
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define *NETCDF*
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#include <errno.h>  /* netcdf functions
> sometimes return system errors */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h: *  The
> netcdf external data types /mingw64/include/netcdf.h: * stored in a
> netCDF file for their associated types. Recall that a C
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_CLASSIC_MODEL 0x0100 /**< Enforce
> classic model on netCDF-4. Mode flag for nc_create(). */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_NETCDF4       0x1000  /**< Use
> netCDF-4/HDF5 format. Mode flag for nc_create(). */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_PNETCDF       (NC_MPIIO) /**<
> \deprecated */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_NOATTCREORD
> 0x20000 /**< Disable the netcdf-4 (hdf5) attribute creation order
> tracking */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_NODIMSCALE_ATTACH
> 0x40000 /**< Disable the netcdf-4 (hdf5) attaching of dimscales to
> variables (#2128) */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h: *  Starting with
> version 3.6, there are different format netCDF files.
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h: *  4.0 introduces the third one. \see
> netcdf_format /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_FORMAT_64BIT
>
> (NC_FORMAT_64BIT_OFFSET) /**< \deprecated Saved for compatibility.
> Use NC_FORMAT_64BIT_OFFSET or NC_FORMAT_64BIT_DATA, from netCDF 4.4.0
> onwards. */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4
> (3) /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4_CLASSIC (4)
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_FORMAT_ALL
> (NC_64BIT_OFFSET|NC_64BIT_DATA|NC_CLASSIC_MODEL|NC_NETCDF4|NC_UDF0|NC_UDF1)
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_FORMATX_NC_HDF5   (2) /**<
> netCDF-4 subset of HDF5 */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define
> NC_FORMATX_NC_HDF4   (3) /**< netCDF-4 subset of HDF4 */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_FORMATX_PNETCDF   (4)
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_FORMAT_PNETCDF
> NC_FORMATX_PNETCDF /**< \deprecated As of 4.4.0, use
> NC_FORMATX_PNETCDF */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:In the classic netCDF
> model there are maximum values for the number of
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:These maximums are not used for
> netCDF-4/HDF5 files unless they were /mingw64/include/netcdf.h: *
> storage models, which should be handled transparently by netcdf */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:/** The netcdf version 3 functions all
> return integer error status. /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:/** Not a
> netcdf id. /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:The specified netCDF ID does not
> refer to an /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:open netCDF dataset. */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_ENFILE   (-34)      /**< Too many
> netcdfs open */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_EEXIST   (-35)
>
> /**< netcdf file exists && NC_NOCLOBBER */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:/** Operation not allowed in data mode. This
> is returned for netCDF /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:classic or 64-bit
> offset files, or for netCDF-4 files, when they were
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:The specified netCDF is in define mode
> rather than data mode. /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:With netCDF-4/HDF5
> files, this error will not occur, unless
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:classic or 64-bit offset file, or an
> netCDF-4 file with /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define
> NC_EBADTYPE   (-45)      /**< Not a netcdf data type */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:classic or 64-bit offset file, or an
> netCDF-4 file with /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:The variable ID is
> invalid for the specified netCDF dataset. */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_ENOTNC   (-51)      /**< Not a netcdf
> file */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_EINTERNAL     (-92)
> /**< NetCDF Library Internal Error */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_EPNETCDF      (-93)      /**<
> Error at PnetCDF layer */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:/* The following
> was added in support of netcdf-4. Make all netcdf-4
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:   error codes < -100 so that errors can be
> added to netcdf-3 if /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_ENOTNC4
> (-111)    /**< Attempting netcdf-4 operation on netcdf-3 file. */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_ESTRICTNC3    (-112)    /**<
> Attempting netcdf-4 operation on strict nc3 netcdf-4 file. */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_ENOTNC3       (-113)    /**<
> Attempting netcdf-3 operation on netcdf-4 file. */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC_ENOTBUILT     (-128)    /**<
> Attempt to use feature that was not turned on when netCDF was built.
> */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define NC4_LAST_ERROR   (-142)    /**< @internal All netCDF errors > this. */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:/**
> @internal This is used in netCDF-4 files for dimensions without
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#define DIM_WITHOUT_VARIABLE "This is a
> netCDF dimension but not a netCDF variable."
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#if defined(DLL_NETCDF) /* define when
> library is a DLL */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#endif  /*
> defined(DLL_NETCDF) */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#if
> defined(DLL_NETCDF) /* define when library is a DLL */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:/* Extra netcdf-4 stuff. */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h: * NC_FORMAT_CDF5, NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4, or
> NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4_CLASSIC */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:/* The next
> function is for NetCDF-4 only */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:/* Added in
> 3.6.1 to return format of netCDF file. */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:Should work for any netcdf format.
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:Should work for any netcdf format.
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:/* Show the netCDF library's in-memory
> metadata for a file. */ /mingw64/include/netcdf.h: * C data type
> corresponding to a netCDF NC_LONG argument, a signed 32
> /mingw64/include/netcdf.h:#endif /* *NETCDF* */
> /mingw64/include/netcdf_aux.h: *   See netcdf/COPYRIGHT file for
> copying and redistribution conditions. /mingw64/include/netcdf_aux.h:
>
> - In order to use any of the netcdf_XXX.h files, it is necessary /mingw64/include/netcdf_aux.h: * to include netcdf.h followed by any
>   netcdf_XXX.h files. /mingw64/include/netcdf_aux.h: * Various things
>   (like EXTERNL) are defined in netcdf.h /mingw64/include/netcdf_aux.h:
> - to make them available for use by the netcdf_XXX.h files. /mingw64/include/netcdf_aux.h:Should work for any netcdf format.
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_aux.h:WARNING: deprecated in favor the
>   corresponding function in netcdf.h. /mingw64/include/netcdf_aux.h:/*
>   Wrappers to export selected functions from libnetcdf */
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h: * In order to use any of the
>   netcdf_XXX.h files, it is necessary
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h: * to include netcdf.h followed by
>   any netcdf_XXX.h files. /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h: * Various
>   things (like EXTERNL) are defined in netcdf.h
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h: * to make them available for use
>   by the netcdf_XXX.h files. /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h: * table
>   contains a pointer to every netcdf function. When a file is
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h: * dispatch table to use, and all
>   subsequent netCDF calls for that /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h: *
>   tables for HDF5, HDF4, pnetcdf, etc.
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h:#ifndef NETCDF_DISPATCH_H
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h:#define NETCDF_DISPATCH_H
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h:/* This is the dispatch table, with
>   a pointer to each netCDF /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h:/* Note
>   the following are specific to netcdf4, but must still be
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h:   netcdf client code even when the
>   file is a classic file; they /mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h:#endif
>   /* NETCDF_DISPATCH_H */ /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter.h: * In order
>   to use any of the netcdf_XXX.h files, it is necessary
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter.h: * to include netcdf.h followed by
>   any netcdf_XXX.h files. /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter.h: * Various
>   things (like EXTERNL) are defined in netcdf.h
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter.h: * to make them available for use by
>   the netcdf_XXX.h files. /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter.h:#ifndef
>   NETCDF_FILTER_H /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter.h:#define
>   NETCDF_FILTER_H 1 /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter.h:#endif /*
>   NETCDF_FILTER_H */ /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter_build.h:#ifndef
>   NETCDF_FILTER_BUILD_H /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter_build.h:#define
>   NETCDF_FILTER_BUILD_H 1
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter_build.h:#include
>   "netcdf_filter_hdf5_build.h"
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter_build.h:@return -- a netcdf-c error
>   code. /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter_build.h:@return -- a netcdf-c
>   error code. /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter_build.h:@return -- a
>   netcdf-c error code. /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter_build.h:@return --
>   a netcdf-c error code. /mingw64/include/netcdf_filter_build.h:#endif
>   /*NETCDF_FILTER_BUILD_H*/ /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:#ifndef
>   NETCDF_JSON_H /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:#define NETCDF_JSON_H 1
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:/* Inside libnetcdf and for plugins,
>   export the json symbols */ /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:#ifdef
>   NETCDF_JSON_H /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:#endif /*NETCDF_JSON_H*/
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:#ifndef NETCDF_JSON_H
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:#endif /*NETCDF_JSON_H*/
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:    make makenetcdfjson
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:#ifdef NETCDF_JSON_H
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:#else /*!NETCDF_JSON_H*/
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:#endif /*NETCDF_JSON_H*/
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:netcdf_supresswarnings(void)
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h:    ignore =
>   (void*)netcdf_supresswarnings; /mingw64/include/netcdf_mem.h:/*! \file
>   netcdf_mem.h /mingw64/include/netcdf_mem.h: * In order to use any of
>   the netcdf_XXX.h files, it is necessary /mingw64/include/netcdf_mem.h:
> - to include netcdf.h followed by any netcdf_XXX.h files. /mingw64/include/netcdf_mem.h: * Various things (like EXTERNL) are
>   defined in netcdf.h /mingw64/include/netcdf_mem.h: * to make them
>   available for use by the netcdf_XXX.h files.
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_mem.h:#ifndef NETCDF_MEM_H
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_mem.h:#define NETCDF_MEM_H 1
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_mem.h:#endif /* NETCDF_MEM_H */
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h:/*! \file netcdf_meta.h
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h: * Meta information for libnetcdf which
>   can be used by other packages which /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h: *
>   depend on libnetcdf. /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h: * how libnetcdf
>   was built.  It will not be required to /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h:
> - of libnetcdf. This should ideally only happen when configuring /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h: * a project which depends on
>   libnetcdf.  At configure time, /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h:#ifndef
>   NETCDF_META_H /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h:#define NETCDF_META_H
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h:#define NC_VERSION_MAJOR 4 /*!<
>   netcdf-c major version. */ /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h:#define
>   NC_VERSION_MINOR 9 /*!< netcdf-c minor version. */
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h:#define NC_VERSION_PATCH 2 /*!<
>   netcdf-c patch version. */ /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h:#define
>   NC_VERSION_NOTE  "" /*!< netcdf-c note. May be blank. */
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h:/*! netcdf-c version string.
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h: * The format of the netcdf-c version
>   string is as follows: /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h:#define
>   NC_HAS_PNETCDF   0 /*!< PnetCDF support. */
>   /mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h:#define NC_HAS_PARALLEL  0 /*!<
>   parallel IO support via HDF5 and/or PnetCDF. */
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:# NetCDF Configuration
>   Summary /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:####### The input
>   file was netCDFConfig.cmake.in                            ########
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(NetCDFVersion
>   "4.9.2")
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set_and_check(netCDF_INSTALL_PREFIX
>   "${PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR}")
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set_and_check(netCDF_INCLUDE_DIR
>   "${PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR}/include")
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set_and_check(netCDF_LIB_DIR
>   "${PACKAGE_PREFIX_DIR}/lib")
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_LIBRARIES
>   netCDF::netcdf)
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/netCDFTargets.cmake")
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_C_COMPILER
>   "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/bin/gcc.exe")
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_C_COMPILER_FLAGS
>   "-march=nocona -msahf -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
>   -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -fmacro-prefix-map='${_SRCDIR}/netcdf-c-4.9.2'=. -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3 -DNDEBUG") /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_C_CPP_FLAGS "
>   ") /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_LDFLAGS
>   "-pipe ")
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_AM_CFLAGS "")
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_AM_CPPFLAGS
>   "") /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_AM_LDFLAGS
>   "") /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_SHARED
>   yes) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_STATIC
>   no) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_NC2
>   yes) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_NC4
>   yes) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_HDF4
>   no) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_HDF5
>   yes)
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_PNETCDF
>   no)
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_PARALLEL
>   no) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_DAP
>   no) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_DAP2
>   no) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_DAP4
>   no)
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_DISKLESS
>   yes) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_MMAP
>   no) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake:set(netCDF_HAS_JNA
>   no) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets-release.cmake:# Import
>   target "netCDF::netcdf" for configuration "RELEASE"
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets-release.cmake:set_property(TARGET
>   netCDF::netcdf APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets-release.cmake:set_target_properties(netCDF::netcdf
>   PROPERTIES /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets-release.cmake:
>   IMPORTED_IMPLIB_RELEASE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libnetcdf.dll.a"
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets-release.cmake:
>   IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/bin/libnetcdf.dll"
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets-release.cmake:list(APPEND
>   _cmake_import_check_targets netCDF::netcdf ) /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets-release.cmake:list(APPEND
>   _cmake_import_check_files_for_netCDF::netcdf "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libnetcdf.dll.a"
>   "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/bin/libnetcdf.dll" )
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets.cmake:foreach(_cmake_expected_target
>   IN ITEMS netCDF::netcdf)
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets.cmake:# Create imported target
>   netCDF::netcdf
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets.cmake:add_library(netCDF::netcdf
>   SHARED IMPORTED)
>   /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets.cmake:set_target_properties(netCDF::netcdf
>   PROPERTIES /mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets.cmake:file(GLOB
>   _cmake_config_files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/netCDFTargets-*.cmake") Binary file /mingw64/lib/libnetcdf.dll.a matches
>   /mingw64/lib/libnetcdf.settings:# NetCDF C Configuration Summary
>   /mingw64/lib/libnetcdf.settings:NetCDF Version:       4.9.2
>   /mingw64/lib/libnetcdf.settings:CFLAGS:           -march=nocona -msahf
>   -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -fmacro-prefix-map='${_SRCDIR}/netcdf-c-4.9.2'=. -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3 -DNDEBUG /mingw64/lib/libnetcdf.settings:NetCDF-2 API:     yes
>   /mingw64/lib/libnetcdf.settings:NetCDF-4 API:     yes
>   /mingw64/lib/libnetcdf.settings:PnetCDF Support:  no
>   /mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/netcdf.pc:Name: netCDF
>   /mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/netcdf.pc:Description: NetCDF Client Library
>   for C /mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/netcdf.pc:URL:
>   https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf
>   /mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/netcdf.pc:Libs: -L${libdir} -lnetcdf
>   /mingw64/lib/python3.10/mimetypes.py:        '.cdf'    :
>   'application/x-netcdf', /mingw64/lib/python3.10/mimetypes.py:
>   '.nc'     : 'application/x-netcdf',
>   /mingw64/lib/python3.10/test/mime.types:application/x-netcdf              nc cdf
>   Binary file
>   /mingw64/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/mimetypes.cpython-310.opt-1.pyc
>   matches Binary file
>   /mingw64/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/mimetypes.cpython-310.opt-2.pyc
>   matches Binary file
>   /mingw64/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/mimetypes.cpython-310.pyc matches
>   /mingw64/share/doc/hdf5/COPYING:(netCDF), The Independent JPEG Group
>   (JPEG), Jean-loup Gailly and Mark Adler
>   /mingw64/share/doc/hdf5/RELEASE.txt:      New test failures in
>   parallel netCDF started occurring with debug
>   /usr/lib/python3.11/mimetypes.py:        '.cdf'    :
>   'application/x-netcdf', /usr/lib/python3.11/mimetypes.py:        '.nc'
>   : 'application/x-netcdf',
>   /usr/lib/python3.11/test/mime.types:application/x-netcdf              nc cdf
>   Binary file
>   /usr/lib/python3.11/**pycache**/mimetypes.cpython-311.opt-1.pyc
>   matches Binary file
>   /usr/lib/python3.11/**pycache**/mimetypes.cpython-311.opt-2.pyc
>   matches Binary file
>   /usr/lib/python3.11/**pycache**/mimetypes.cpython-311.pyc matches
>   Binary file /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc matches
>   /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/LWP/media.types:application/x-netcdf             nc
>   cdf
>   /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/MIME/Parser/Filer.pm:application/x-netcdf        .cdf
>   /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/MIME/Parser/Filer.pm:application/x-netcdf        .nc
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/desc:mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/desc:mingw-w64-netcdf
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/desc:https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/bin/libnetcdf.dll
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/include/netcdf.h
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/include/netcdf_aux.h
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/include/netcdf_dispatch.h
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/include/netcdf_filter.h
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/include/netcdf_filter_build.h /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/include/netcdf_json.h
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/include/netcdf_mem.h
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/include/netcdf_meta.h
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfig.cmake
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFConfigVersion.cmake
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets-release.cmake
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/lib/cmake/netCDF/netCDFTargets.cmake
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/lib/libnetcdf.dll.a
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/lib/libnetcdf.settings
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/netcdf.pc
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/share/licenses/netcdf/
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/share/licenses/netcdf/COPYRIGHT
>   /var/lib/pacman/local/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1/files:mingw64/share/man/man3/netcdf.3.gz
>   /var/log/pacman.log:[2023-07-04T19:40:17-0700] [PACMAN] Running
>   '/usr/bin/pacman --noconfirm -U
>   /c/mingw-w64-netcdf/mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf-4.9.2-1-any.pkg.tar.zst'
>   /var/log/pacman.log:[2023-07-04T19:40:18-0700] [ALPM] installed
>   mingw-w64-x86_64-netcdf (4.9.2-1) Binary file /proc/1177/cmdline
>   matches Binary file /proc/1177/environ matches Binary file
>   /proc/1189/cmdline matches Binary file /proc/1189/environ matches

Answer (score 1):

This problem is **solved** using **set_target_properties()**:

```
# set netcdf library element according to operating system
if(WIN32 OR MINGW)
    # look for mingw64 path to use it as relative path for library and include paths
    find_program(MINGW64_GXX g++)
    get_filename_component(MINGW64_BASE_DIR ${MINGW64_GXX} DIRECTORY)
    get_filename_component(MINGW64_INSTALL_DIR ${MINGW64_BASE_DIR} DIRECTORY)
    message(STATUS "[CMakeLists.txt:cedbManagement]: MINGW64_INSTALL_DIR ${MINGW64_INSTALL_DIR}")
    
    add_library("netcdf" STATIC IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(netcdf PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "${MINGW64_INSTALL_DIR}/bin/libnetcdf.dll"
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${MINGW64_INSTALL_DIR}/include/")

    set(NETCDF_LIB "netcdf")
else() # Linux or Mac
    set(NETCDF_LIB _trycompile_netcdf::NetCDF)
endif()

message(STATUS "[CMakeLists.txt:cedbManagement]: NETCDF_LIB ${NETCDF_LIB}")

# Build library and test and install library
buildAndInstallTarget("CedbManagement" "${sources}" "${test_sources}" "DMF03::"
                    LIB_DEPENDENCIES DMF03::Common ${NETCDF_LIB} DMF03::Geometry DMF03::FocusWrapper
                    WITH_TESTING ${BUILD_TESTING_DMF03}
                    TEST_WORKING_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../data")
```

There was also a misspelled include, with:

> #include "netcdf"

instead of:

> #include "netcdf.h"

That was part of the problem.